# Is adding the new data point not at the end of array a bad idea?

Tags: algorithm, data-visualization

This involves a design decision.  An interviewer asked me to write something to plot the data assuming there are 100 data points, and new data point comes in (and given to the program) every 0.1, 0.3 or 0.5 or 1 second. (it can change in the future, and I think the smallest granularity on a common web browser is 0.03 seconds).

I proceeded to think about adding the new data point to the Nth position in the array. For example, adding the data at array entry 36, and plot the data from 37th to 99th, and then from 0th to 36th.  Next time, add the data at array entry 37, and plot the data from 38th to 99th, and then from 0th to 37th.

This way, we don't need to "unshift" (shift out) the data at entry 0 and therefore needing to shift entry 1 to 99 one place forward, and then add the new data point at entry 99, and then plot data entry 0 to 99.

For some reason, the interviewer gave a big frown, and said, "why would we do that? It is not heavy to shift 99 data over." I said what if there are 500 or 1000 data point we'd like to plot in the future, we might want to avoid shifting data about 500 times or 1000 time each time when a new data point comes in.

He mentioned "let's say we just shift them anyway".

Is shifting the data actually not an issue or concern?  What if on the screen we have 10 or 15 of such widgets, apps, or webpages, to monitor 15 types of data, we might want to avoid shifting 15,000 data entries constantly.

Comment: Are all of the data points visible at once?  I can't tell if the question is about the computational load of an array insert or of redrawing the plot.

Comment: I wonder if interviewer is probing for your thoughts on handling redraw quickly, e.g. using bit-blit operation to scoot old data over and plot only the new point.

Comment: yes, the data is plotted as values vs time, so all data is visible at once... can you do bit-blit on a webpage?  It seems there is, but is it good to use it in this situation? I also thought if we never did such a type of widget before, then not knowing to use a bit-blit might be normal and might not deserve a big frown in this case: https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/graphics-and-imaging/2078-canvas-bitmap-operations-bitblt-in-javascript.html

Comment: Yes. HTML5 canvas allows for this.  You can create a canvas and drawing context independent of the displayed canvas and perform drawing operations on both.

Comment: if the graph region is 200 x 200 pixels, does bit-blit involve shifting close to 200 x 200 = 40,000 pixels over? Or maybe it involves the graphics card and can be considered to be a single operation instead of 40,000 steps, and I'd imagine the graphics card can support doing 15, 20 of such bit-blit simultaneously on screen. (bit-blit might appear to be quite low level and I might have thought of video games using it when the player go up the galaxy or go to the right side of the scene constantly such as in Super Mario Bros)

Comment: but then if I "clear the canvas" and draw 100 data point, clearing the canvas also involves touching 200 x 200 = 40,000 pixels, unless if I clear out each data dot (which might be 2x2) but there might be "left over shadow" due to perhaps dithering if I do that. (say if the widget can be used as 800 x 800 and each dot is 6 x 6 round dot)

Comment: The first idea which comes to mind would be to save the canvas, upon a new point, to restore the image with some shift, and plot the new point. This looks awkward/complicated if point is an outlier and requires some log transformation of the graph. So I would (maybe mistakenly) just redraw the whole stuff every 0.x seconds. As for the shifting, I think you do a micro optimization: you may as well push your points say for up to 500 and take the ```[i,i+100[``` range. When 500 reached, move ```[400;500[``` to ```[0;100[```. Or just rely on a [queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/queue-fifo)

Answer (score 1):

I naively tried to load n canvas to the page, and compared the time needed to plot against the time taken shifting array.

tldr: Whichever method is used to shift the points, the method is negligible against the time needed to plot the points. (~ 3%)

---

I only run the code in ff70 with casual js.
(For instance I am stocking an array of objects even though optimization may be available if I stock only floats)

There are two kind of measures: push and refresh.

- push measures the time needed to shift a point and add a new one
- refresh measures the time needed to replot the canvas

Below three approaches for pushing: either push (Array.prototype.(shift|push), tail to a queue (and move the head), or nopole's approach

Every 10ms I plot the time spent in the `push` method. On top of the picture, the cumulative time spent. I stop once a run has reached 100 points and reload the page for another run.

The y axis is the same accross all runs

1. Push

[image: push 0/2]
[image: push 1/2]
[image: push 2/2]

push avg: (838+886+864)/3 = 862ms

2. Queue

[image: queue 0/2]
[image: queue 1/2]
[image: queue 2/2]

push avg: (625+760+825)/3 = 736ms

refresh avg: (40554+39934+40915+39194+39264+30480)/6 = 38390ms

3. Nopole

[image: nopole 0/2]
[image: nopole 1/2]
[image: nopole 2/2]

push avg: (792+861+871)/3 = 841ms

Notice that for one sample: (625/30480) we seem to have benefited from some cpu willing to work. So the shifting method feels even more irrelevant.

It is hard to tell which approach is better, because of the few samples drought for each kind of methods and it is likely more an issue of cpu's overall workload rather than the page itself

To reproduce

```js
let timerPush = 0
let timerRefresh = 0
class Canvas {
  constructor (f, el, period) {
    this.w = 300
    this.h = 300
    this.points = []
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    canvas.style.cssText = 'background:#eeeeee; margin:10px;'
    canvas.width = this.w
    canvas.height = this.h
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    this.ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, this.h / 2)
    this.ctx.lineWidth = 1
    this.dw = this.w / this.MAX_POINTS
    this.dh = this.h / 2
    el.appendChild(canvas)

    let x = 0
    this.timer = setInterval(_ => {
      x += period
      this.push({ x, y: f(x) })
      this.refresh()
    }, period * 1000)
  }

  refresh () {
    const now = performance.now()
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, -this.h / 2, this.w, this.h)
    this.ctx.beginPath()
    this._plot()
    this.ctx.stroke()
    this.ctx.closePath()
    timerRefresh += performance.now() - now
  }

  push (p) {
    const now = performance.now()
    this._push(p)
    timerPush += performance.now() - now
  }

  _plot () {
    if (!this.points.length) { return }
    this.ctx.moveTo(0 * this.dw, this.points[0].y * this.dh)
    for (let i = 1; i < this.points.length; ++i) {
      const p = this.points[i]
      this.ctx.lineTo(i * this.dw, p.y * this.dh)
    }
  }

  _push (p) {
    if (this.points.length == this.MAX_POINTS) {
      this.points.shift()
    }
    this.points.push(p)
  }

  MAX_POINTS = 100
}

class CanvasQueue extends Canvas {
  constructor () {
    super(...arguments)
    this.tail = {}
    this.head = this.tail
    this.n = 0
  }

  _plot () {
    if (!this.head.next.p) return
    let node = this.head.next
    this.ctx.moveTo(0 * this.dw, node.p.y * this.dh)

    let i = 1
    node = node.next
    while (node) {
      this.ctx.lineTo(i * this.dw, node.p.y * this.dh)

      ++i
      node = node.next
    }
  }

  _push (p) {
    if (this.n === this.MAX_POINTS) {
      this.head = this.head.next
    } else {
      this.n++
    }
    const node = { p }
    this.tail.next = node
    this.tail = node
  }
}

class CanvasNopole extends Canvas {
  constructor () {
    super(...arguments)
    this.start = 0
  }

  _plot () {
    if (!this.points.length) { return }
    const s = this.start
    let z = 1
    let startBack = 0
    if (this.points[s]){
      this.ctx.moveTo(0 * this.dw, this.points[s].y * this.dh)
      for (let i = s+1; i < this.points.length; ++i) {
        const p = this.points[i]
        this.ctx.lineTo(z++ * this.dw, p.y * this.dh)
      }
    }else{
      this.ctx.moveTo(0 * this.dw, this.points[0].y * this.dh)
      startBack = 1
    }

    for (let i = startBack; i < s; ++i) {
      const p = this.points[i]
      this.ctx.lineTo(z++ * this.dw, p.y * this.dh)
    }
  }

  _push (p) {
    this.points[this.start] = p
    this.start = (this.start + 1) % this.MAX_POINTS
  }
}

class CanvasSummary extends Canvas {
  constructor () {
    super(...arguments)
    this.ctx.resetTransform()
    this.ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, this.h)
    // we know beforehand that timer should not grow bigger
    const deltaTimer = 50
    this.dh = this.h / deltaTimer
    this.old = timerPush
  }

  refresh () {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.w, this.h)
    this.ctx.beginPath()
    this.ctx.resetTransform()
    this.ctx.fillText(`push: ${timerPush} plot: ${timerRefresh}`, 5, 20)
    this.ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, this.h)
    this._plot()
    this.ctx.stroke()
    this.ctx.closePath()
  }

  push (p) {
    this._push(p)
  }
}
function run () {
  const $summary = document.querySelector('.summary')
  const $bench = document.querySelector('.bench')
  const cs = new CanvasSummary(x => {
    if (cs.points.length === cs.MAX_POINTS) {
      clearInterval(cs.timer)
    }
    const y = timerPush - cs.old
    cs.old = timerPush
    return y
  }, $summary, 1)

  //const canvas = Array(30).fill(0).map(x => new Canvas(Math.sin, $bench, 0.01))
  //const canvas = Array(30).fill(0).map(x => new CanvasQueue(Math.sin, $bench, 0.01))
  const canvas = Array(30).fill(0).map(x => new CanvasNopole(Math.sin, $bench, 0.01))
}
run()
```

```html
<section class="summary"></section>
  <hr/>
  <div class="bench"></div>
```

Comment: do you mean if the time to plot the graph is 1, then shifting 100 data points in the array is only 3% of that? I suppose if it is 200 or 300 points, then it is also 3%. The graph was a simpler dot type, so I think it may be simpler, so the 3% ratio could be bigger.  But I think if it is an interview question, then it is hard to say which way to go. In real life, we might go with the "shift the data 100 times" to begin with, and seeing it slow, then make it no need to shift so many times each time. (or probably do a profiling to see how much time is spent the most to make it run faster).

Comment: On a side note I do like your optimization (just would not want to debug it) and should have included it in the bench

Comment: I might have moved everything into `addDataPoint()` and `getDataPoint` and everything will be self-contained, and when it works well together with the unit tests, probably it doesn't need much change in the future... I felt it was somewhat reasonable to not to do a move of data 99 times, and if suggesting possibly doing it, would it actually deserve a big frown if it is in an interview for which the candidate might not have done real time graphs like that before.

Comment: Also if the graphics card is powerful, and the "dot" is by imposing some bitmap sprite at a coordinate, could it be super fast and the shifting of data point 99 times is much more than 3% of the time needed

Comment: I have included your method, numbers are not good but I don't think it can be incombed to your method. Rather my implem or the cpu's random dedication. Even the rounding of performance.now could be the reason. Regarding the freezing once again keep it mind that while your method works and is alluring from "sparing" memory, optmizing the pushing was probably not what was hoping the interviewer. The freezing may be perceived as "all he is saying is bullshit" but it can also be "I don't want te interview to enter into those sort of details". (Was the freezing ok is even subjective at this point)

Comment: your time of 40915 is how much time? I suppose it is not 40.9 seconds? Is it 0.0409 seconds?

Comment: time is in same unit of [performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now). You can also reread the post. I gave the units...

Comment: ok at first I didn't understand the answer too well as I got confused what a "push" is... when I read "I only run the code in ff70" and I didn't know what ff70 is and I read quickly and skipped past your definition of what a "push" is.  So I read the time under the graph is "ms", meaning it is millisecond, or 1/1000 of a second.  So it was 862ms... and how many pushes was that?  I wanted to know because I didn't know whether your program was doing the plot efficiently.

Comment: When in the interview, I was able to plot the graph of 100 data point within a 33ms duration. So every 33ms, a new data point comes in, and a new graph was able to be plotted. But I guess it makes sense, that 3% of that is 1ms, and computers nowadays can do 2 billion steps in the processor each second (say, a 2GHz processor), so converting the JS into machine code (more like interpreting), it is reasonable that the processor can shift 100 data in 1ms

Comment: but would plotting the data actually take 33 times as the "shifting of 100 data"? Now, is it doing a "clear canvas" efficiently? The canvas might be able to be cleared in a slow way (drawing a white square on top), or in a fast way somehow by the GPU. And besides, you never know what the interviewer may say. He may say, "You wouldn't want to shift 100 data each time. The monitoring computer can be used for other tasks as well. We wouldn't want to burden the computer much now, do we?"

Comment: And one reason of not wanting to shift data 100 times is because it is common to take array shifting as an ineffective way of handling data, so a common practice is to not have an array and shifting data or try to avoid it whenever possible. OTOH, some people may claim, the width of the screen is typically 3800 pixel wide max, and O(3800n) is the same as O(n), so we wouldn't care, and somebody actually may say if the sorting algorithm is O(n log n), we will use one rather than the other because the constant factor is better (with QuickSort than MergeSort)

Comment: I don't think you are asking for help (?) anymore and I am not the interviewer either. I have stated that perf-wise, shifting method does not matter (in relation to each other, in ratio with plot time). I also have stated that it is easier to shift+push than alternatives. I somehow fraily backed it up with numbers. You state not shifting is more effective and better practice (which I generally agree for the former part). For the latter, I would say you are doing pessimization (fair enough) except that you include complexity.

Comment: I am doing exploration and want to find the truth about it. One reason I am trying to check for your "plotting" is whether you are sure about plotting will really take 33 times the time needed for shifting the array, especially with the graphics card / GPU so powerful nowadays (for example, does the graph plotting have hardware acceleration turned on). But if your plotting is in fact very efficient, then the conclusion is in fact, shifting the data IS not needed.

Comment: I can't go much further (because measuring takes time, and I am not _that_ interested in measuring canvas api). That said, keep in mind that here, shifting and canvas preprocessing could be parallelized in [webworkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas)

Comment: I think I understand ff70 as Firefox version 70.x... I think your suggestion is good if the shifting is only 3% of the time needed. There is usually a concern such as in FAANG interviews if they say data comes in all day long, say N times and N can be a million, then how do you do something (such as finding the medium constantly). If I have a O(N²) solution for the all-day scenario, I heard they typically don't like it as the solution they want is at most O(N log N). Why? If N is a million, O(N²) is 1,000,000,000,000 and O(N log N) is 6,000,000, but if one multiplier is 100 it should be ok